# Converting Integer to Byte in Java

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
    int i =128;
    byte b = (byte) i;
    System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(i)); //10000000
    System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(b)); //11111111111111111111111110000000
```

could someone explain why 1's were added to the left when casting from Integer to Byte and how could a byte carry more than 8 bits !?

Comment: `Integer#toBinaryString` accepts an `int`, not a `byte`. The `byte` value is widened to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.toBinaryString` on the Integer class, so your number is treated as an Integer in any case.

The reason the second call has so many 1 is because it is a negative number. In Java, bytes are signed, so the maximum positive value is 127. By casting 128 into a byte you are actually representing -128. When you cast that small negative number into an 32 bit signed integer as you were doing, all those 1s appear at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks you pointed to the problem but actually there is no Byte.toBinaryString(i) :|